# my mental issue and my obligations as a Muslim contradict

Tags: salat, masjid, men, medical

assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh
so i want to ask, I'm a teenager Muslim male, but i, for my entire life i rarely pray at masjid because my social anxiety, im afraid to meet another people and it's really hard to overcome it, but regardless i still do my prayer at home, so am i sinful for not praying in the masjid?

People told me my prayer is valid but I'm still committing a sin by not going to masjid even though im physically well, but like i said, im really afraid of meeting another people or talk or just look at them, i still do my Friday pray at the masjid but even then i still am feel uncomfortable being around a lot of people, this really affect my social life, but i don't know what to do

I hope i can overcome my social anxiety, but for the time being, is my prayer still a valid but sinful pray?

im sorry im not that good at English but i hope whoever reading this get the point I'm trying to say

wassalamu'alaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh

Comment: Yes ignoring some uncommon opinions, Salah is valid even if it is not offered in congregation. However there is difference among the madhabs on whether praying in congregation is wajib, fard al-kifaya or sunnah mu'akkadah.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As for your inquiry it was already addressed before in [Will my salah be accepted if I pray at home?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/30642/will-my-salah-be-accepted-if-i-pray-at-home) and to some extent in [Not praying in masjid when imam is a government paid employee](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/31060/not-praying-in-masjid-when-imam-is-a-government-paid-employee).

Comment: My advice would be to only go there when the Jam-at/Congregation is about to start and leave after the imam does Salam, this way you would not need to interact with the people at the mosque because everyone there would be in congregation. It is better to pray the Nafl prayer at home, As for Jumuah, enter the mosque Arabic  kutba/sermon starts and leave after praying fard.

Answer (score 2):

> I hope I can overcome my social anxiety, but for the time being, is my prayer still valid but sinful?

Wikipedia says:

> Social anxiety disorder (SAD), also known as social phobia, is an anxiety disorder characterized by sentiments of fear and anxiety in social situations, causing considerable distress and impaired ability to function in at least some aspects of daily life.[5]: 15  These fears can be triggered by perceived or actual scrutiny from others. Individuals with social anxiety disorder fear negative evaluations from other people.

Social anxiety is a recognized clinical disorder. Therefore, it is a medical condition.

[Sura Al Bakarah: 286](https://quran.com/en/al-baqarah/286) says that:

> لَا يُكَلِّفُ ٱللَّهُ نَفْسًا إِلَّا وُسْعَهَا ۚ لَهَا مَا كَسَبَتْ وَعَلَيْهَا مَا ٱكْتَسَبَتْ ۗ رَبَّنَا لَا تُؤَاخِذْنَآ إِن نَّسِينَآ أَوْ أَخْطَأْنَا ۚ رَبَّنَا وَلَا تَحْمِلْ عَلَيْنَآ إِصْرًۭا كَمَا حَمَلْتَهُۥ عَلَى ٱلَّذِينَ مِن قَبْلِنَا ۚ رَبَّنَا وَلَا تُحَمِّلْنَا مَا لَا طَاقَةَ لَنَا بِهِۦ ۖ وَٱعْفُ عَنَّا وَٱغْفِرْ لَنَا وَٱرْحَمْنَآ ۚ أَنتَ مَوْلَىٰنَا فَٱنصُرْنَا عَلَى ٱلْقَوْمِ ٱلْكَـٰفِرِينَ ٢٨٦

**Translation**

> Allah does not require of any soul more than what it can afford. All good will be for its own benefit, and all evil will be to its own loss. ˹The believers pray,˺ “Our Lord! Do not punish us if we forget or make a mistake. Our Lord! Do not place a burden on us like the one you placed on those before us. Our Lord! Do not burden us with what we cannot bear. Pardon us, forgive us, and have mercy on us. You are our ˹only˺ Guardian. So grant us victory over the disbelieving people.”

Therefore, continue what you are doing right now.

However, it would be best if you focused on getting psychiatric treatment as soon as possible to eliminate this phobia.

Not treating a disease, whether physical or mental, [is a bad practice](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3855).

> حَدَّثَنَا حَفْصُ بْنُ عُمَرَ النَّمَرِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ زِيَادِ بْنِ عِلاَقَةَ، عَنْ أُسَامَةَ بْنِ شَرِيكٍ، قَالَ أَتَيْتُ النَّبِيَّ صلى الله عليه وسلم وَأَصْحَابُهُ كَأَنَّمَا عَلَى رُءُوسِهِمُ الطَّيْرُ فَسَلَّمْتُ ثُمَّ قَعَدْتُ فَجَاءَ الأَعْرَابُ مِنْ هَا هُنَا وَهَا هُنَا فَقَالُوا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ أَنَتَدَاوَى فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ تَدَاوَوْا فَإِنَّ اللَّهَ عَزَّ وَجَلَّ لَمْ يَضَعْ دَاءً إِلاَّ وَضَعَ لَهُ دَوَاءً غَيْرَ دَاءٍ وَاحِدٍ الْهَرَمُ ‏"‏ ‏.‏

**Translation**

> I came to the Prophet (ﷺ) and his Companions were sitting as if they had birds on their heads. I saluted and sat down. The desert Arabs then came from here and there. They asked: Messenger of Allah, should we make use of medical treatment? He replied: Make use of medical treatment, for Allah has not made a disease without appointing a remedy for it, with the exception of one disease, namely old age.